# SQL SELECT INTO OUTFILE Not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql, bash

I am stuck with an SQL query running from a bash script.

The following works and outputs the file as expected but there are some fields that contain commas and I would like these fields to be included but have the commas escaped.

```
FILE="/var/lib/mysql-files/UMHP/ConditionAssessment.csv"
mysql --user='root' --password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' UMHPSurvey << EOFMYSQL

SELECT 
DateEntry AS 'Entry Date',
FirstName AS 'First Name',
LastName As 'Last Name',
member_id as 'Member ID',
mobile AS 'Mobile',
Doctor AS 'Need help getting connected to a doctor',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Asthma%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Asthma',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%COPD%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'COPD',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Cancer' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Cancer',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%CHF%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'CHF',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Diabetes%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Diabetes',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Hypertension (High Blood Pressure)%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Hypertension (High Blood Pressure)',
AdditionalConditionsDescription AS 'Additional Health Conditions',
MedicationQuestions AS 'Questions about meds',
InsuranceQuestionsDescription AS 'Healthcare concerns'
FROM UMHPSurvey.Assessment
where Doctor = 'Yes' or ConditionQuestions = 'Yes' or AdditionalConditions = 'Yes'
or MedicationQuestions = 'Yes' or Concerns = 'Yes'
INTO OUTFILE '$FILE' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
EOFMYSQL
```

The following doesn't

```
FILE="/var/lib/mysql-files/ConditionAssessment.csv"
mysql --user='root' --password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' UMHPSurvey << EOFMYSQL

SELECT 
DateEntry AS 'Entry Date',
FirstName AS 'First Name',
LastName As 'Last Name',
member_id as 'Member ID',
mobile AS 'Mobile',
Doctor AS 'Need help getting connected to a doctor',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Asthma%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Asthma',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%COPD%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'COPD',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Cancer' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Cancer',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%CHF%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'CHF',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Diabetes%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Diabetes',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Hypertension (High Blood Pressure)%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Hypertension (High Blood Pressure)',
AdditionalConditionsDescription AS 'Additional Health Conditions',
MedicationQuestions AS 'Questions about meds',
InsuranceQuestionsDescription AS 'Healthcare concerns'
FROM UMHPSurvey.Assessment
where Doctor = 'Yes' or ConditionQuestions = 'Yes' or AdditionalConditions = 'Yes'
or MedicationQuestions = 'Yes' or Concerns = 'Yes'
INTO OUTFILE '$FILE' 
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
EOFMYSQL
```

Giving the error below

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR at line 2: Unknown command '\"'.
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

I have also tried the following

```
FILE="/var/lib/mysql-files/ConditionAssessment.csv"
mysql --user='root' --password='xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' UMHPSurvey << EOFMYSQL

SELECT 
DateEntry AS 'Entry Date',
FirstName AS 'First Name',
LastName As 'Last Name',
member_id as 'Member ID',
mobile AS 'Mobile',
Doctor AS 'Need help getting connected to a doctor',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Asthma%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Asthma',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%COPD%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'COPD',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Cancer' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Cancer',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%CHF%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'CHF',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Diabetes%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Diabetes',
CASE WHEN HealthConditions LIKE '%Hypertension (High Blood Pressure)%' THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END AS 'Hypertension (High Blood Pressure)',
AdditionalConditionsDescription AS 'Additional Health Conditions',
MedicationQuestions AS 'Questions about meds',
InsuranceQuestionsDescription AS 'Healthcare concerns'
INTO OUTFILE '$FILE' 
FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '\"' 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
FROM UMHPSurvey.Assessment
where Doctor = 'Yes' or ConditionQuestions = 'Yes' or AdditionalConditions = 'Yes'
or MedicationQuestions = 'Yes' or Concerns = 'Yes'
EOFMYSQL
```

Giving the same error (below)

```
mysql: [Warning] Using a password on the command line interface can be insecure.
ERROR at line 2: Unknown command '\"'.
```

Can anyone help me understand where I am going wrong

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're using parameter expansion to substitute `$FILE`, you also get backslash quoting inside the "here document".
 What the shell is sending to MySQL looks like this:

`FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\'`

Try double-escaping the backslash:

`FIELDS ESCAPED BY '\\\\'`

You other use of backslash is unaffected.
This is confusing.
Read that [section of the the manual](https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bashref.html#Here-Documents) carefully.
To debug the here document, replace your call to mysql with cat:

`cat - << EOFMYSQL`

Comment: Using the actual file location and double escaping fixed the issue.